# What happened to Terrel?

Tags: plot-explanation, moonlight

At the end of part 2 of [***Moonlight***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4975722/), when

> Chiron attacks Terrel with a chair in school, he looks to be unconscious on the floor.

Chiron then

> gets sent to a juvenile prison

for this, but I don't know if it ever explains the extent to which he was punished, or what crime he ultimately committed.

What happened to Terrel after the incident?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### We don't know.

All we know is that Chiron

> assaulted him with the chair. Certainly he was injured but we don't know the severity of the injuries.

Given that Chiron is only sent to juvie it's *extremely* unlikely that Terrel was killed.

> Thus a charge of the **Assault** variety would seem likely but that is also unknown. We also don't know how long Chiron was in juvie but most age out of the juvenile system at 18, assuming he was tried as a minor.

However, there is a 10 year time jump between the assault and when we see Chiron again so any sentence would have been less than that since Chiron has now relocated to another city, is considerably larger than before *and* is now established as a drug dealer.